# How to capture an anchor value from url in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, anchor

After updating or creating a record I use url helper to redirect to the part on the page where the record happened to be located:

```
if record.save
  ....
  redirect_to records_url, :anchor => "record_" + record_id.to_s
end
```

the resulting url will be something like

http://localhost:3000/records#record_343242

I want to highlight the record using jquery or prototype, and the anchor is the exact id that I am looking for. Can I capture it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you're trying to capture it in JavaScript?

```
var record_id = window.location.href.hash.split("_")[1];
```

In Prototype you could write:

```
var record_id = window.location.href.hash.split("_").last;
```